# ionic-cache-src not working in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, image-caching

I want to use image cache in my ionic app, I found ionic-cache-src in google, but after I try use that, that's not working, just show blank rectangle.
here is my code :

```
<img cache-src={{values.service_parkingsite_imagefilepath}} alt="" style="height:80px; width:100px;">
```

note : values.service_parkingsite_imagefilepath is https url.

I have also follow all instalation step in https://libraries.io/bower/ionic-cache-src, anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You may replace image with div by setting `src-is` to `background`.